# PostgreSQL, get statements of a running transaction

Tags: postgresql

If I execute a transaction like:

```
begin;
update test set a=2;                                                                                           
select pg_sleep(9999);
```

I will get a RowExclusiveLock on test.

If I try to see which query is in that pid pg_sleep will be shown (because it is the currently running query).

Is there any option to get the query that actually create the lock?

Or maybe a query to get all the statements of the running transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that.  Unless you have very verbose logging turned on (like `log_statement=all`) and can mine that data out of the server log file.

I think it would be a nice feature to optionally store some limited amount of data (like 4096 bytes, but configurable) of "prior transaction context" for each backend and then exposing it through pg_stat_actvity, and maybe logging it for log_lock_waits or deadlock errors.  But as far as I know there is no active work going on to add such a feature.